# All the nodes gathered at one place - GraphStream - JAVA

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, graphstream

I am working on [GraphStream](http://graphstream-project.org/) Library for java. But I am facing a problem here.
When I try to get the nodes from the DB Table it shows the data along with edges on JPanel but at first, when program starts, it gathered all the nodes at one place like this image. So, I have to drag all the nodes. 
Why this is happening ? Any little hint would be appreciated.

[image]

Here is my code :

```
public class GraphExplore {
    static Connection conn2;
    static String result, result2;
    static int totalRows, i;

    public static void main(String args[]) throws SQLException {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    showData();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private static void showData() throws SQLException {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(30, 50, 1300, 600);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout()){
            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return new Dimension(640, 480);
            }
        };
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.blue, 5));
        Graph graph = new SingleGraph("Tutorial", false, true);

        try {
            Class.forName("org.h2.Driver");
            conn2 = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:file:G:/hs_data/h2_db/test", "sa", "sa");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Statement stmt2 = conn2.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt2.executeQuery("SELECT count(*) FROM cdr");
        while (rs.next()) {
            totalRows = rs.getInt(1);
        }
        ResultSet rs2 = stmt2.executeQuery("SELECT ANUMBER,BNUMBER FROM CDR LIMIT 1000");
        while (rs2.next()) {
            result = rs2.getString("ANUMBER");
            result2 = rs2.getString("BNUMBER");
            graph.addNode(result);
            graph.addNode(result2);
            for (i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
                graph.addEdge("string" + i, result, result2);
        }

        Viewer viewer = new Viewer(graph, Viewer.ThreadingModel.GRAPH_IN_GUI_THREAD);
        ViewPanel viewPanel = viewer.addDefaultView(false);
        panel.add(viewPanel);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        for (Node node : graph) {
            node.addAttribute("ui.label", node.getId());
        }

        }

}
```

Before that I was using `graph.display()` and it was working fine But when I added the graph panel to my custom JPanel it starts behaving like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
   viewer.enableAutoLayout();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this function after desabeling autolayout:

```java
//desable autolayout
viewer.disableAutoLayout();

//set a random node positions
setNodePositions();
```

Where the function setNodePositions() is defined as the following:

```java
private void setNodePositions(){       
   Random r = new Random();
   for(Node node:graph.getNodeSet()){
       if(!node.hasAttribute("xyz")){
           node.addAttribute("xyz",r.nextInt(x_max), r.nextInt(y_max), 0);
       }
   }                                
}
```

x_max and y_max are the width and the height of your panel.